# How can I create a for loop to run for all values 0-n but other than a particular value?

Tags: c++

It currently terminates at j=5 and I want it to somehow skip j=5 iteration and continue till j<10.

```
for(int j=0; j!=5 && j<10 ; j++)
{ 
    cout<<"loop working for j = "<<j<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    if (j == 5)
      continue;    
    std::cout << "loop working for j = " << j << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, yet another version

```
for(auto j: std::initializer_list<int>{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9}) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int j=0; j<10 ; j++)
{
if(j != 5){
cout<<"loop working for j = "<<j<<endl;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For example you can write the following way

```
for ( int j = 0; j < 10 ; ++j )
{

    if ( j != 5 ) cout << "loop working for j = " << j << endl;

}
```

or

```
for ( int j = 0; j < 10 ; j += ( j == 4 ) + 1 )
{

    cout << "loop working for j = " << j << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also increment the counter in a dedicated function. Here's an example with a lambda function:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto const incrementSkippingFive = [](int& j)
    {
        if (j == 4)
        {
            j += 2;
        }
        else
        {
            ++j;
        }
    };

    for (int j = 0; j < 10; incrementSkippingFive(j))
    { 
        std::cout << "loop working for j = " << j << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course c++ should always be written as expressively as possible:

```
int main()
{
    for (auto i : everything.from(1).to(9).except(5))
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Of course this requires some trivial supporting code. This can go in a library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct range
{
    range(int x, int y)
    {
        while (x < y) {
            values.push_back(x++);
        }
    }

    void remove(int z)
    {
        values.erase(std::remove(std::begin(values),
                                 std::end(values), z),
                     std::end(values));
    }

    range except(int z) const {
        auto result = *this;
        result.remove(z);
        return result;
    }

    auto begin() const {
        return std::begin(values);
    }

    auto end() const {
        return std::end(values);
    }

    std::vector<int> values;
};

struct from_clause
{
    int x;

    range to(int y) const { return range(x, y + 1); }
};

struct range_builder
{
    from_clause from(int n) const { return from_clause{n}; }

};

constexpr range_builder everything {};
```

expected results:

```
1
2
3
4
6
7
8
9
```

> Are you serious?

;-)